# adding at the top of listView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am using list View in my app ,When my application receives the messages they are stored in the database and then are added to the list view ,but every time app receive the new message they are stored at the end of the list which is not a good practise to store new message at end, I want to put my all new messages at the top of the list , what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: You need to sort the listview items on the basis of date and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`insert()` on `ArrayAdapter<>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29) to insert at position `0`, which will not only update the `ArrayList<>` that you are wrapping with the `ArrayAdapter<>`, but also will trigger your `ListView` to update and show the new entry.

Comment: then what about the last message stored at the 0th position? Will it move to 1?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, everything else slides down one position.